# How to send multiple SMS from desktop through Windows Phone?

Tags: sms, windows-7

Is there some way to edit and send SMS from a desktop PC through Windows Phone <strike>, via USB</strike> ? Sent to approx. thirty numbers. The message is similar, however each includes some info specific to the individual recipient, like mail merge.

Comment: I can do the mail merge beforehand and then send individual messages.

Comment: With Windows 10 OS and Windows 10 mobile you can respond to text messages received on your phone through the action center interface on the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to edit and send SMS from a desktop PC through
>   Windows Phone, via USB?

No. You cannot access the SMS in Windows Phone via a USB connection.

---

However the latest insider preview helps you to manage SMS from PC via Internet. This is achieved through the Skype app. Keep in mind that it is still in preview.

---

In a Windows 10 PC, You can use Cortana to send replies to any incoming messages directly from Action center. This requires an active internet connection.

Comment: Via Internet would be fine too. Unfortunately I'm currently stuck with Win 7.

Comment: @RobKam That's really unfortunate. This feature may not come to Windows 7.

Comment: Had you been on Windows 10, I'd have also highlighted that Cortana lets you reply to SMS from the desktop

Comment: @RowlandShaw I have used Cortana to reply messages from my PC. But RobKam asked that he want to edit and send a message to 30 people.That is not possible with Cortana. You cannot create a message. You can only reply to an incoming message. So i did not bother to include it in my answer at first. Anyway I will update my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: I don't mind sending the messages one at a time, but they're not in reply.